# How to remove an event from only one div on which event is performed

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

```
let popped = 0;

document.addEventListener('click', function(e){

if (e.target.className === "balloon"){
    
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#ededed";
            e.target.textContent = "POP!";
            popped++;
            removevent(e);               
            checkAllPopped();
}
```

});

```
function removevent(e) {
    e.target.removeEventListener('click',function() {})
}
```

I am trying to remove the event once the user clicks on the div. But no matter how I try to put the removeEventListenever it doesn't work. I tried doing it with custom function like:

```
function abc(e) {
//some code
}
document.addEventListener('click',abc,true)
document.removeEventListener('click',abc,true)
```

Still, this didn't work out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to remove an event listener on a case-by-case basis, consider adding individual event listeners to each balloon. Then, within the handler function, you can remove it from each ballon as it's "popped."

```js
let popped = 0;

const balloons = document.querySelectorAll('.balloon');

function handler(e){
    if (e.target.className === "balloon"){
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#ededed";
      e.target.textContent = "POP!";
      popped++;
      console.log(popped);
      e.target.removeEventListener('click', handler);
    }
  }

for (let balloon of balloons) {
  balloon.addEventListener('click', handler);
}
```

```html
<div class="balloon">Balloon</div>
<div class="balloon">Balloon</div>
<div class="balloon">Balloon</div>
<div class="balloon">Balloon</div>
<div class="balloon">Balloon</div>
```

Comment: This works but I'm trying to do it with removeEventListener.

Comment: Not sure that's feasible with your current approach. You have attached the event listener to the document, so you'll be catching all click events lower in the DOM tree. I don't believe you can selectively disregard certain elements.

Comment: What if i add events to all divs with querySelectorAll?

Comment: yeah, that would certainly be doable then! Let me see if I can rig something up

Comment: I'll try too. Thanks for help

Comment: OK, updated with handling event listeners on a case-by-case basis